# Problems with creating nodes with XmlWriter -- "mis" as prefix

Tags: c, xml, xmlwriter

My first attempt to generate this type of file, not very familiar, please help me.
I want to achieve the following effect

```
 <ExtendedData xmlns:mis="www.dji.com">
   <mis:actions param="240" label="zoom" >CameraZoom</mis:actions>
</ExtendedData>
```

my code is

```
 writer.WriteStartElement("mis", "ExtendedData", "www.dji.com");
 writer.WriteStartElement("mis", "actions", "www.dji.com");
                writer.WriteAttributeString("param", "240");
                writer.WriteAttributeString("label", "zoom");
                writer.WriteString("CameraZoom");
                writer.WriteEndElement();
```

It works like this:

```
 <mis:ExtendedData xmlns:mis="www.dji.com">
   <mis:actions param="240" label="zoom" >CameraZoom</mis:actions>
</mis:ExtendedData>
```

What do I need to do to remove the "mis:" prefix from " <mis:ExtendedData xmlns:mis="www.dji.com">"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Microsoft documentation (I assume this is the .NET XmlWriter?) gives the example

```
// Write an element (this one is the root).
writer.WriteStartElement("book");

// Write the namespace declaration.
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "bk", null, "urn:samples");
```

for writing a no-namespace element with a namespace declaration that's not actually used in the element name.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I have tried this way of writing, and there will be other problems when writing this way, I will edit my question again, please read it again

Comment: If it's a different problem then please raise a new question rather than editing a previous question. Otherwise it's very difficult for people coming here in future to follow the thread.

Comment: Thank you very much, I took a closer look and succeeded, I have achieved the desired effect, and I was just confused. . .
I've been using **" writer.WriteStartElement ("o", "customer", "http://oreilly.com");
writer.WriteElementString ("o", "firstname","http://oreilly.com","Jim");
writer.WriteEndElement();"**This way of writing.
Thank you very much for your reply and suggestions.